# creating classes and method headers

Tags: java

I'm doing revision questions for an upcoming test and I'm stuck on one part of one of the questions. We were given a snippet of code from a 'Driver' class and asked to create the classes and method headers needed to get the driver to compile. The driver code is as follows;
public class Driver

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Marker m1 = new Marker(“red”); Marker m2 = new Marker(“blue”);
        m1.drawLine(7.3);
        int val = m2.getUses();
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble with the last 2 lines of code. If anyone could help me out, or even just tell me what direction to go with it, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
Public class Marker{
   private String color;

   public Marker(String color){
     this.color = color;
   }

   public void drawLine(Double length){
     //do something
   }

   public int getUses(){
     // do something
   }
 }
```

- The object constructor accepts a String of color to denote the color of the Marker.
- drawLine is a void method because it doesn't return anything.  It apparently accepts in a number of type Double (7.3) and draws something.
- No idea what getUses does but you know it returns an int because of the variable on the left side of the equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `m1` and `m2` are objects of the `Marker` class.

`Marker m1 = new Marker(“red”)` expects that `Marker` class has a constructor, with `String` as an argument.
Also, when you say `m1.drawLine()` or `m2.getUses()`, it expects Marker class to have these methods.

So, create a marker class and add the above methods with the correct signatures, (i.e. proper parameters and return type).